# Unexpected poor performance of AdaBoost compared to Random Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, random-forest, adaboost

I am working on a lithology identification project similar to the one described [here](https://github.com/seg/tutorials-2016/blob/master/1610_Facies_classification/manuscript/facies_classification.md).

So far the **Random Forest** method has yielded satisfying results. I decided to compare its performance with that of other algorithms, namely **AdaBoost** and **Support Vector Machines**.

I therefore modified my training model function as follows:

```
def train_model(training_data, features, labels, method):
    X=training_data[features]  # Features
    y=training_data[labels]  # Labels
    print(y.value_counts())
    if method == 'random_forest':
        clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, min_samples_split = 5, min_samples_leaf = 4, max_depth = 10, bootstrap = True))
    elif method == 'adaboost':
        clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0))
    elif method == 'svm':
        clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), SVC(gamma='auto'))
    else:
        print("method not yet supported")
    print(method)
    print(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5))
    classifier = clf.fit(X,y)
    return clf
```

The function printed the following scores:

> adaboost [0.48272892 0.52855543 0.79712267 0.62000345 0.50964852]

> svm [0.73589456 0.77233181 0.67117505 0.69150586 0.76162991]

> random_forest [0.74700663 0.81169782 0.71183666 0.702102   0.73664714]

I was surprised to see that the values returned by `cross_val_score` were much lower than those obtained using the two other methods. Does this make sense or is there an issue with the way I am calling the AdaBoost classifier in my pipeline: `AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)`?

Please not that I did not start tuning the hyperparameters through random search, but in my experience, the improvements associated with hyperparameter tuning are only marginal.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer for your question? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No, I kept working with random forests so far. If you are facing a similar issue, I suggest asking your question on Cross Validated - Stack Exchange (https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where I hope it will receive more attention that my Stack Overflow post.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, if any answers please post.

Comment: Hi @Dulangi_Kanchana. Unfortunately, I have not received any answer to this question and  ended up using RF intsead of Adaboost. I would suggest posting your question on the "Cross Validated" Stack Exchange (or on "Data Science"). Hopefully your post will receive more attention than mine!